# Delete node: Remove header, footer and rightbar in delete node page

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to remove the header, footer and rightbar in a delete node page (node/.../delete). How can this be reached?

I already tried editing page--node--delete.tpl.php, but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow suggestion from this link for page **https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions**

If you have created a page using views then you can call template for views like (page--viewname.tpl.php).

if you go with the content node, You need to call template like (page--node--nodeid.tpl.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to do this for all delete pages (node/.../delete) pages on my site, so no specific node id.

Comment: Ohh. Go to your theme directory and enter templates folder after create file name "page--node--delete.tpl.php" add your code to this file. It will call when you reached node/nid/delete

Comment: I tried page--node--delete.tpl.php, but this does not work

Comment: You can also find which template is calling for the active page!! Go on default folder edit setting.php and enable # $conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE; (remove #). 

Now go to active page and open developer tools using F12 (window/ubuntu) and check HTML code. 

You will find red comment link which define template file.